# Dismissing view from UIWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest when opening app store

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am using a `webStoryViewController` which uses `UIWebView` to process web pages. It is called modally from other screens when user clicks on a web link. If app store link is found then I have a code to dismiss my view and open app store. It opens link in app store fine but fails to dismiss my view most of the times. So when I come back to my app I see a blank window. It does work sometimes though. Any ideas how I can make it happen every time? Thanks in advance!

Here is my code

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{   
    NSURL *url = request.URL;

    if (![url.scheme isEqual:@"http"] && ![url.scheme isEqual:@"https"]) {
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:url]) {
            [webView stopLoading];
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    else
       return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. It was getting into a race condition. So UIView was not getting enough time to close out the view before app went into background. So I put dismissModalView call with delay like this

```
[self performSelector:@selector(actionDismissView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
```

That did the trick!!